# (Discord.JS) user.createdAt Property problem

Tags: javascript, discord.js

If I use `${user.createdAt}`/`${message.author.createdAt}` the bot will send: 'Fri Oct 20 2017 22:12:32 GMT+0200 (Ora legale dell’Europa centrale)'.

How can I make the bot send only: 'Fri Oct 20 2017 22:12'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to use some sort of date formatting. You could use [`toLocaleString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString):

```js
// obviously user will be an actual user
const user = {createdAt: new Date()}

console.log(user.createdAt.toLocaleString('en', {
  weekday: 'short',
  month: 'short',
  day: 'numeric',
  year: 'numeric',
  hour: '2-digit',
  hour12: false,
  minute: 'numeric'
}))

// to output exactly what you said (removes commas):
console.log(user.createdAt.toLocaleString('en', {
  weekday: 'short',
  month: 'short',
  day: 'numeric',
  year: 'numeric',
  hour: '2-digit',
  hour12: false,
  minute: 'numeric'
}).replace(/,/g, ''))
```

You could also use a library to format dates such as [moment](https://momentjs.com), [luxon](https://github.com/moment/luxon#readme), [date-fns](https://date-fns.org), or [day.js](https://day.js.org).